# How to remove curly brackets from a list of functions?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

When I'm creating a plot I standardize the format by predefined parameters, like:

```
PlotFormat := {Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> Medium}; 
ListPlot[list,PlotFormat]
```

PlotFormat is now a list of the parameters in curly brackets

```
{Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> Medium}
```

and works pretty well for the `ListPlot` and `ListLinePlot` command.
However, if I use `Plot[]` instead, it doesn't work, because of the curly brackets.

Is there a way to remove the curly brackets from `PlotFormat` to obtain

```
Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Blue, ImageSize -> Medium
```

?

Thank you

Comment: `Evaluate@PlotFormat`

Comment: @Syed It is interesting why one has to apply Evaluate in Plot, but does not need in ListPlot. Do you know the answer?

Comment: The reason is, that Plot has the attribute "HoldAll" and ListPlot not.

Comment: I don't know why some `*Plot` commands have the `HoldAll` attribute and others don't.

Comment: I think you might be better off using `SetOptions`.

Comment: @Syed `Plot` is `HoldAll` because otherwise it would not be able to localize the dummy variable and something like `x = 1; Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]` would fail.

Comment: Your problem is solved now, but you asked about removing the outer braces. If you wanted to do that for some other reason look into `Splice` and also `Sequence`.